# Retornar um endereço

Tags: java, android, google-location-api

Estou finalizando um projeto onde abrirá um alertDialog. Assim que o usuário pressionar OK irá fazer uma confirmação e sua localização será informada por um toast. Gostaria de saber como eu consigo retornar o local onde o usuário está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça desse jeito:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Faço o objeto da classe
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        assert locationManager != null;
        //Requesto a localização, os parâmetros 500 e 0 são intervalo que irei pegar o localização e a variação em metros que irei pegar respectivamente
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0, locationListener);

    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                   //Peguei a latitude e longitude
                   double lat = loc.getLatitude();
                   double log = loc.getLongitude();

                   //Agora transformo em endereço:
                   String cityName = null;
                   Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                   List<Address> addresses;
                   try {
                        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                        loc.getLongitude(), 1);

                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                           //Aqui você chama seu alert, o endereço se pega da maneira abaixo:
                           //Endereço = addresses.get(0).getLocality());

                           System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                           cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

                        }
                    }catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                   //Depois de pegar a localização eu para o onLocationChanged
                   locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        }
}
```

Mais mastigado que isso só se eu fizer seu alertDialog kkkkkkkkkk, lembre-se de fazer um método que checa se o GPS está ativo antes de tentar pegar a localização, pois pode ocorrer uma exceção se ele estiver desligado.

Lembrando que você deve adicionar no Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: kkkk muito obrigado salvou dms, o alert ja ta pronto kk

Comment: @BrunoSIlva então marca como aceita aí pra fortalecer a amizade kkkk

Comment: claro kkk, vlw parceiro

Comment: Aqui mais uma duvida, e se eu quiser chamar o alert e dependendo do que ele solicitar ai sim eu retorno a localização?

Comment: No ok no alert vc chama: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0, locationListener);`

Comment: Vlw novamente, brigadao

Comment: De nada parceiro :)